# Java Heap Space Error due to add function

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, jsf-2

Whenever I am calling the getFriendList function from the xhtml page I am getting an exception. The page keeps on loading and after that I stop the browser. I get the given stackstrace. Its is telling me that there is an error at line no.78 `friends.add(friend);` . I think there is something wrong with my syntax. It would be helpful if someone point the error.

1)Here is my FriendBean it is request scoped.

```
package com.bean;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import com.entity.Friend;
import com.entity.User;

public class FriendBean {

    Friend friend;
    private EntityManager em;
    public FriendBean(){
        friend = new Friend();
        EntityManagerFactory emf=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("FreeBird");
         em =emf.createEntityManager();
    }
    public Friend getFriend() {
        return friend;
    }
    public void setFriend(Friend friend) {
        this.friend = friend;
    }
    public List<Friend> getFriendRequestList(){
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext().getSession(true);
        User user=(User) session.getAttribute("userdet");
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT f FROM Friend f WHERE f.email='"+user.getEmail()+"' AND f.status=0",Friend.class);
          List<Friend> results =query.getResultList();
          return results;


    }
    public String friendAccept(String friendRequestId){

        System.out.println("friend accept called...");
        Friend f=em.find(Friend.class,Integer.parseInt(friendRequestId));
        f.setStatus(1);
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(f);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        Friend viceversa=new Friend();
        viceversa.setEmail(f.getFriendEmail());
        viceversa.setFriendEmail(f.getEmail());
        viceversa.setStatus(1);
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(viceversa);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        return "success";

    }
    public String friendReject(String friendRequestId){
        System.out.println("friend reject called..");
        Friend f = em.find(Friend.class,Integer.parseInt(friendRequestId));
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.remove(f);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        return "success";
    }
    public List<User> getFriendList(){

        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext().getSession(true);
        User user=(User) session.getAttribute("userdet");
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT f FROM Friend f WHERE f.email='"+user.getEmail()+"' AND f.status=1",Friend.class);
         List<Friend> results =query.getResultList();
         ArrayList<User> friends = new ArrayList<User>();

         while(results.listIterator().hasNext()){
             User friend =em.find(User.class,results.listIterator().next().getFriendEmail());
             friends.add(friend);
         }
          return friends;

    }
}
```

2)Here is the exception that I am getting.

```
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/Home.xhtml]
javax.el.ELException: /Home.xhtml @146,59 value="#{friendBean.friendList}": java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:731)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1798)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndexWithoutRowStatePreserved(UIData.java:484)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:473)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.encodeBegin(TableRenderer.java:81)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:820)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.encodeBegin(UIData.java:1118)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1755)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2245)
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2219)
    at java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:213)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(ArrayList.java:187)
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:411)
    at com.bean.FriendBean.getFriendList(FriendBean.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:363)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:138)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:224)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:731)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1798)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndexWithoutRowStatePreserved(UIData.java:484)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:473)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.encodeBegin(TableRenderer.java:81)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:820)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.encodeBegin(UIData.java:1118)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1755)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)

WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2245)
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2219)
    at java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:213)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(ArrayList.java:187)
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:411)
    at com.bean.FriendBean.getFriendList(FriendBean.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:363)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:138)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:224)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:731)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1798)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndexWithoutRowStatePreserved(UIData.java:484)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:473)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.encodeBegin(TableRenderer.java:81)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:820)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.encodeBegin(UIData.java:1118)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1755)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
```

Comment: Your SQL statement is opening your application up to SQL Injection... tsk tsk tsk.. :) You'd be better off using a PreparedStatement and adding the parameter to it. See how to do that here: docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html Also some background on SQL Injection: owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java

Comment: @DomenicD. I was about to write it :), good point. Another thing is that this line : `HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext().getSession(true);` means : If a _session_ doesn't exist then **create new**. I suppose that's not what you want. So use `getSession(false)` instead - if a _session_ exists then get it otherwise don't create new and get `null`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are clearly running into an issue where your Tomcat server instance has not been allocated enough memory to the JVM heap space.  An OutOfMemoryError will be thrown when the allocated heap space has been completely consumed.

You can allocate more through the Tomcat Windows application or you can set in catalina.bat or catalina.sh

Example:

> set CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m

Comment: I agree with this. As a side note though, your SQL statement is opening your application up to SQL Injection... tsk tsk tsk.. :) 

You'd be better off using a `PreparedStatement` and adding the parameter to it. See how to do that here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html Also some background on SQL Injection: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java

Comment: @DomenicD. Good find, but you should add this as a comment to the question so that the OP will be aware.  Commenting this on my answer means that this person will never be notified :)